# How to convert non-nullable type to nullable in C++/CLI?

Tags: generics, c++-cli, nullable

How to convert non-nullable type to nullable in C++/CLI?

I know how to do it in C#:

```
public Type GetNullableType(Type t)
{
    return typeof(Nullable<>).MakeGenericType(t);
}
```

But I can't figure out, how to convert it to C++/CLI.

I have tried this, but when I compile the code, I get internal compiler error as a result.

```
Type^ nullableType = Nullable<>.GetType();
return nullableType->MakeGenericType(t);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another less brittle workaround:

```
static Type^ GetNullableType(Type^ t)
{
    Type^ nullable = Nullable<int>::typeid->GetGenericTypeDefinition();
    return nullable->MakeGenericType(t);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, instead of C# `typeof()`, you use `typeid` in C++. So, `typeof(int)` becomes `int::typeid`.

Second, when referencing generic types, it seems you just omit the angle brackets. So, `typeof(List<>)` becomes `List::typeid`.

The problem with this is that you can't specify the number of type arguments. And `Nullable::typeid` returns the type of the non-generic static class `Nullable`, which is not what we want.

I didn't find out a way to get the type directly from C++/CLI. But you can always use `Type.GetType()`:

```
Type^ nullableType = Type::GetType("System.Nullable`1");
return nullableType->MakeGenericType(t);
```

(The `` `1 `` is the way .Net internally uses to distinguish types with different count of type arguments.)

This will stop working if the `Nullable<T>` type is ever moved out of mscorlib, but I doubt that will happen.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Is it ok to write:

`Type^ nullableType = Type::GetType("System.Nullable`1");`